# React onChange method not working in react_on_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-on-rails

I am trying to create a sample app based on [`react_on_rails`](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) gem. In my react code react inbuild function like `onChange` or `onSubmit` are not working.

My `HelloWorldWidget` Component looks like this.

```
...
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context); 
  _.bindAll(this, 'handleChange');
}

handleChange(e) {
  const name = e.target.value;
  console.log(name);
  //this.props.updateName(name);
}

render() {
  const { name } = this.props;
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h3>
        Hello, {name}!
      </h3>
      <input className="form-control input-sm col-sm-4" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
  </div>
  );
}
```

Also if I disable server side pre-render of my component in my `views/hello_world/index.html.erb` file then the component is not rendering on UI.

```
<%= react_component("HelloWorldApp", props: @hello_world_props , prerender: false) %>
```

Github Repo: [react-on-rails-sample-app](https://github.com/ssolanki/react-on-rails-sample-app)

Comment: do you get errors? and what is `_.bindAll(this, 'handleChange');`?

Comment: No errors. It is lodash function which binds all our functions to `this` context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where `_.bindAll` method came from but the orthodox way of binding handlers is with this syntax:
`this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`

If you use arrow function you don't need to bind it to the `class`;

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  const name = e.target.value;
  console.log(name);
  //this.props.updateName(name);
}
```

Comment: `_.bindAll` is a lodash function to bind multiple functions together. I tried with `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);` but it is same, not logs in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use arrow functions like this:

```
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but not worked. This issue might be because of server side rendering is true, but I am not sure exactly what is going on.